# Is it possible to get intellij to print out variables/expressions to the console at a breakpoint?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Basically I have a library calling my code, the library has a variable that I'd like to inspect at each iteration of a loop.  I can stop the debugger in that code and intellij can inspect it, but I cannot add a println to the code as it's an external precompiled library.

Basically I'm wondering if intellij can do anything to help me out?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific value of this variable? If so, you can use conditional breakpoints - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/breakpoints.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Main menu | Run | Evaluate Expression...`

[image]

Or configure the breakpoint to do it:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct.  The functionality required is essentially a breakpoint, but instead of breaking execution, it should run an expression.  I think this just allows a expression to be run by hand when the debugger is paused, but I need to do this a few hundred times to get the result I'm after.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: unset "suspend" checkbox and it will not stop - just evaluate the expression and continue execution